# IOS: tag for search page in device

Tags: ios, device

Is possible search an app (in search page) with other words? 
In my device I can find my app only if I write words of bundle display name and not with other word...How can I solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not perfectly true, spotlight is also searching by the AppStore names, you'll need to think both the best short (usually one-word: "MyApp") and long names ("MyApp Crazy Music") yourself :)